# How do I open the device's default navigation app through a URL?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Good Morning,  everyone

I'm dealing with a problem in an application developed using Cordova, for android. In a certain page of the application (everything is constructed using pure HTML and Javascript), I need to open a route when the user clicks a link. After many hours of research on the internet, I could find some options, but none of them dealed with it.

Here I give you what I found and tried so far. Please assume that the coordinates represent a viable location for the route..

---

Using the `geo:` schema

Example: `<a href="geo:45.6,23.4">Route</a>`

Problem: This was the one that nearly solve it. The problem here is that `geo:` opens the map application showing the position given in the coordinates. All fine until there, but there is no option using this schema to open with a route, as I could figure out reading [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870).

---

Using `maps.google.com` in the link domain. Example: `<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"></a>`

When trying this using the device's browser, I could open the navigation app. But using it inside a hybrid application as the on I'm building just redirects it to Google Maps site, using it's mobile version. But it happens inside my **application**, what now seems logical to me but really freaked me out, since it's not possible to control that. (Unfortunally an iframe is not a viable option because of the standarts that we addopt in the project.
Using a `target=blank` on that link didn't changed nothing.

---

My last try was using the `google.navigation` schema.

Example: `<a href="google.navigation:q=45.6,32.8" target="_blank">`
Again, if I test it in a common device browser everything works just fine but when I try it on my app it crashes, saying that "google.navitation is not a supported protocol."

---

*UPDATE*

---

I've also tried the option present [here](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/18/reintroducing-google-maps/), with the following format:

`<a href="comgooglemaps://?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit">Route to here</a>`

The application also crashes and I'm alerted that the `comgooglemaps://` schema is not supported.

---

I could findthese 4 options, since everyone that had similar needs could find a solution using them. Is there any other way to do that?  I really appretiate any help from you, if possible, with some documentation/specification/whatever link about that.

Thank you for your attention.